# 504 (Outdated Optimize Dep)

Tags: reactjs, import, jsx, react-virtualized

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6VBj.png)

this is the error

```
import 'react-virtualized/styles.css';import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import './App.css'import React from 'react';
import useToggle from '../hooks/useToggle';
import { devices } from './devices'import 'react-virtualized/styles.css';
import { CellMeasurer } from 'react-virtualized/dist/commonjs/CellMeasurer';
import List from 'react-virtualized/dist/commonjs/List';
import AutoSizer from "react-virtualized-auto-sizer";
```

and these are my imports

When i downloaded react-virtualized via npm i had an error when trying to use normal 'react-virtualized' syntax to import List and Autosizer. I had to change the import link cause it was not workingg and it fixed the bug. But when i was trying to import CellMeasurer it broke. I tried several paths and also normal 'react-virtualized' path but nothing seems to work. Can someone help me?